# How to play MP4 video inline on Outlook in-app browser on iPhone devices?

Tags: html, iphone, video, outlook, microsoft-edge

I have an MP4 video on a webpage. The video tag looks something like this.

```
<video src="static/mp4video/themes/samplevideo.mp4" playsinline webkit-playsinline controls></video>
```

The video plays properly on all the devices and browsers except Outlook in-app browser on iPhone 12.

When I am trying to open the webpage from the **Outlook app on iPhone 12**, it opens on the in-app browser. The user-agent for that browser is **"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_8 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"**. The MP4 video in the page is opened on native media player in full screen mode instead of playing on the browser.

I have added **playsinline and webkit-playsinline** attributes as well. This is working on Safari and Chrome browsers as expected, but not on Outlook in-app browser.

I want to play the video on browser and not on full screen mode.